# How to implement "pull down to refresh" on server side

Tags: django, api, pagination, mobile-application

I'm programming the API service, so the iOS app wants to "pull down to refresh" some records (AKA streams), but I'm not sure how to program the "pagination"-like feature.

I was thinking of making a query using offset and limit (start and end in python) but I think this is not the right approach.

Does anyone have an idea how this should be done?

My RESTful API is buit on django.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like Django wouldn't need to do anything if you're truly going for a "refresh and load new content" VS "scroll down to reveal older and older content". It should always return the current latest, while your app can figure out if new elements have been returned vs what's being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to return the latest records, the app should query your API with a `last_updated` timestamp.

Based on that you can filter your queryset to match the records that have been added the last time the user has refreshed his timeline.

If no timestamp is set, you return all records (or a part of it ordered by date of creation).

Comment: Great, but I think I must use the sequential ID instead the date, because there are many records with the same date (maybe not exactly if I consider the seconds, but just to be safe).